# Loading images from assets/images in rails 4 app

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a js.erb file that makes reference to a sprites file which i have stored under app/assets/images

js.erb file

```
this.image.src = "<%= image_path('sprites.png') %>";
```

I have added the following to my config/environment/development.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and ran

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I am still getting a 404 bad request error when trying to load the image. Please help this is taking way longer than it should.

Comment: what is the image url generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **config.assets.compile = true** is in production.rb

and **NO need** to add in development.rb

But if you want to debug assets in development.
You might change this line:

```
config.assets.debug = true // default is false
```

**Additional Info:**

```
image_path("sprites.png")
# => "/assets/sprites.png"

image_url("sprites.png")
# => "http://www.example.com/assets/sprites.png"
```

**To make sure you run the precompile in Development**

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```